# Get Union of all Sets that don't Intersect more efficiently

Tags: python

I would like to get the union of two set of `frozensets`. I'm only interested in the union of `frozensets` that don't intersect. Another way to look at it is that I'm only interested in unions that have a length equal to the total length of both `frozensets` combined. Ideally I would like to ignore any `frozensets` that don't intersect with each other for a massive speedup. I expect many `frozensets` to have at least one element in common.  Here is the code I have so far in python. I would like it to be as fast as possible as I'm working with a large dataset. Each of the `frozensets` are no more then 20 elements but there will be somewhere around 1,000 total in a set. All numbers will be between 0 and 100. I'm open to converting to other types if it would allow my program to run faster but I don't want any repeated elements and order is not important.

```
sets1 = set([frozenset([1,2,3]),frozenset([4,5,6]),frozenset([8,10,11])])
sets2 = set([frozenset([8,9,10]),frozenset([6,7,3])])
newSets = set()
for fset in sets1:
    for fset2 in sets2:
        newSet = fset.union(fset2)
        if len(newSet) == len(fset)+len(fset2):
            newSets.add(frozenset(newSet))
```

the correct output is

```
set(frozenset([1,2,3,8,9,10]),frozenset([4,5,6,8,9,10]),frozenset([8,10,11,6,7,3]))
```

Comment: `{s1 | s2 for s1 in sets1 for s2 in sets2 if s1.isdisjoint(s2)}`

Answer (score 1):

```
sets1 = set([frozenset([1,2,3]),frozenset([4,5,6]),frozenset([8,10,11])])
sets2 = set([frozenset([8,9,10]),frozenset([6,7,3])])




union_ = set()

for s1 in sets1:
    for s2 in sets2:
        if s1.isdisjoint(s2):
            union_.add(s1 | s2)


print(union_)



 {frozenset({3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}), frozenset({1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10}), frozenset({4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10})}
```

Comment: `s1 & s2` will result in creation of an unnecessary set, we can `s1.isdisjoint(s2)` instead of that.